# How do I add two sets?

Tags: python, set

```
a = {'a', 'b', 'c'} 
b = {'d', 'e', 'f'}
```

How do I add the above two sets? I expect the result:

```
c = {'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
```

Answer (score 243):

Compute the union of the sets using:

```
c = a | b
```

Sets are unordered sequences of unique values.  `a | b`, or [`a.union(b)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.union), is the union of the two sets — i.e., a new set with all values found in either set. This is a class of operations called "set operations", which Python [set types](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set-types-set-frozenset) are equipped with.

Comment: You can also do `c |= a | b` if C is already a set and you want to update in place

Answer (score 93):

You can use [`.update()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.update) to combine set `b` into set `a`. Try this:

```
a = {'a', 'b', 'c'}
b = {'d', 'e', 'f'}
a.update(b)
print(a)
```

To create a new set, `c` you first need to [`.copy()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#frozenset.copy) the first set:

```
c = a.copy()
c.update(b)
print(c)
```

Answer (score 11):

Use the result of union() of a and b in c. Note: sorted() is used to print sorted output

```
a = {'a','b','c'} 
b = {'d','e','f'}
c = a.union(b)
print(sorted(c)) #this will print a sorted list
```

Or simply print unsorted union of a and b

```
print(c)  #this will print set c
```

Comment: this prints a list `['a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f']` instead of a set `{'c', 'b', 'f', 'a', 'e', 'd'}`

Comment: print(c) #prints set. 
sorted() will print a sorted list

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to subtract two sets, I tested this:

```
A={'A1','A2','A3'}
B={'B1','B2'}
C={'C1','C2'}
D={'D1','D2','D3'}

All_Staff=A|B|C|D
All_Staff=sorted(All_Staff.difference(B)) 
print("All of the stuff are:",All_Staff)
```

Result:

```
All of the stuff are: ['A1', 'A2', 'A3', 'C1', 'C2', 'D1', 'D2', 'D3']
```

Answer (score 1):

Using unpack:

```py
>>> c = {*a, *b}
>>> c
{'a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e', 'f'}
```