# How to add sets?

Tags: python, python-3.x, set

I have two sets `set([1,2,3]` and  `set([4,5,6]`. I want to add them in order to get set `1,2,3,4,5,6`.

I tried:

```
b = set([1,2,3]).add(set([4,5,6]))
```

but it gives me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-27-d2646d891a38>", line 1, in <module>
    b = set([1,2,3]).add(set([4,5,6]))

TypeError: unhashable type: 'set'
```

**Question:** How to correct my code?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I add two sets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29648520/how-do-i-add-two-sets)

Comment: did you try `a.union(b)'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can take the union of sets with `|`

```
> set([1, 2, 4]) | set([5, 6, 7])
{1, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7}
```

Trying to use `add(set([4,5,6]))` is not working because it tries to add the entire set as a single element rather than the elements in the set — and since it's not hashable, it fails.

Comment: sorry for being pedantic but I think `a.union(b)` is cleaner.

Comment: I don't think that's pedantic @CharlieParker, just an opinion. `a.union(b)` is nice, so is `a | b`. Both loose a little luster when you solve the *actual* problem and write something like: `set([1, 2, 4]).union([5, 6, 7])` or set variables `a` and `b` first to give that nice, clean feel as @khuynh did below.

Comment: perhaps the reason I think it's pedantic is that `|` is usually used for Ors - for booleans. Yes it is isomorphic sort of to set union but the Or of a set doesn't really exist. What exists is the union of them. That's what I meant.

Comment: 'or' makes perfect sense here and the relationship between `or -> union` and `and -> intersection` is [common in the math literature](https://eng.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Computer_Science/Programming_and_Computation_Fundamentals/Foundations_of_Computation_(Critchlow_and_Eck)/02%3A_Sets_Functions_and_Relations/2.02%3A_The_Boolean_Algebra_of_Sets). A union represents items in set A **or** set B. An intersection represents items in set A **and** set B. This is reflected in the choice of `|` and `&` for these operators.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the union operation with the `.union` method or the `|` operator:

```py
>>> a = set([1, 2, 3])
>>> b = set([4, 5, 3])
>>> c = a.union(b)
>>> print(c)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
>>> d = a | b
>>> print(d)
{1, 2, 3, 4, 5}
```

See the complete list of operations for [set](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#set).